# AngularJS : Routing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, href, ngroute

So I was watching an angular tuto and the guy was explaining the 'ngRoute' and how to use it, using this example :

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

myApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'pages/home.html',
            controller: 'mainController'


        })
        .when('/second', {
            templateUrl: 'pages/second.html',
            controller: 'secondController'

        })

});


myApp.controller('mainController', ['$scope', '$route', function ($scope, $route) {




}])
    .controller('secondController', ['$scope', '$route', function ($scope, $route) {




}]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
   <!-- Fixed navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Angular</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#/second">Second</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container">
        
        <div ng-view class="jumbotron"></div>

    </div> <!-- /container -->



        
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.3/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.3/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>



</html>
```

and it worked for him, but for me just the Home link worked while the Second link didn't work until I changed the `<a href="#/second">Second</a>` to `<a href="#!/second">Second</a>`
and it worked, but I don't understand why ?

Comment: Its because of the version you were using. The video you watched might be with angular 1.4 or 1.5. Dont go with ngRoute, try ui-router which is flexible than ngRoute

Comment: yes a friend of mine told that too !
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

you probably use version 1.6 right? . In this 1.6 angular team decided to changing the default $location hash-prefix to '!'  . You can read in

> https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#migrating-from-1-5-to-1-6

Comment: So it was related to the version :/
Thanks man I appreciate your help

Comment: @damer glad for help . if it helpful for you , dont forget accept for me ^^

Answer (score 1):

can you make sure that you don't have the below code from your route file inside config...

$locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');

Comment: yes I think that's the reason why , it's related to the version of angular I'm using
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

myApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'pages/home.html',
            controller: 'mainController'
        })
        .when('/second', {
            templateUrl: 'pages/second.html',
            controller: 'secondController'
        })
});


myApp.controller('mainController', ['$scope', '$route', function ($scope, $route) {
}])
    .controller('secondController', ['$scope', '$route', function ($scope, $route) {
}]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
   <!-- Fixed navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Angular</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#/second">Second</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container">
        
        <div ng-view class="jumbotron"></div>

    </div> <!-- /container -->

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.3/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.3/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn, and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback from users in the form of upvotes, when the code is explained.